# CORS policy for S3 bucket referencing itself

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my css files I have relative paths:

```
.css-emoticon.smile{
      background: url('../../images/sprites.png');
      background-position: -16px -18px ; 
 }
```

But I get a forbidden 403 error for the sprite.png file when pulling it from S3 to load on my site. The css file loads just fine from S3 onto my site.

My S3 is located on a subdomain: http://media.example.com and the site that loads in files from S3 is http://example.com

Here is my CORS file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Any ideas on how to set the CORS policy to allow relative urls in my CSS?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I didn't set the bucket policy to allow access to the ../../images/ folder.

New bucket policy (CORS looked to be correct)

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::media.example.com/prod",
                "arn:aws:s3:::media.example.com/images"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```